# Looping through data and subsetting data according to upper quantile

Tags: r, subset

I'm currently trying to loop through my data, and by determining whether the value falls above the upper quantile I want to then subset the data so that only those that are above the upper quantile are selected. To demonstrate what I mean:-

```
vector <- c()
df <- as.integer(read.table(text = " 88  72  92  38  20  16   8  14   8   4   4   8   6   4   6   2  54 272   2   6"))
for(i in 1:length(df)){
current.bin <- i
window.size <- 5
window <- df[current.bin-window.size : current.bin+window.size]
upper.quant <- quantile(window, 0.95)
if(df[current.bin] > upper.quant){
vector[i] <- current.bin
}
}
str(vector)
 int [1:18] NA NA 3 4 NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

So as I loop through, I want it to look at the values before and after (a window of 5) and use that to determine the upper quantile before deciding as to whether the value it's currently looking at falls above it or not. After that I want to use the current.bin value to then subselect data from another dataframe by using it to specify the rows I want to extract. However when I look at the vector that is produced, it's 2 less than the number of values in my df. I can't figure out why this is happening, any ideas?

Also how would I go about using the position of values that are above the upper quantile to subselect data? Using the df as an example, I want it to go something along the lines of:-

```
df <- df["row positions using values in vector", ]
```

Comment: When I run your code I get the following error: `Error in vector[i] <- current.bin :  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`. Did you copy the right code?

Comment: sorry didn't specify the creation of the vector

Comment: For `i=19` and `i=20` the if-condition is false. Hence there is nothing to assign to `vector[19]`